# Take static file in self hosted Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, self-host-webapi

I like to get static file from the project to browser like `https://localhost:3440/myFile.txt`.

I placed the "myFile.txt" in the root directory near App.config file. But due to some reason I got only 404. Any idea?

About Application

1. WebAPI project, self hosted with Owin
2. No IIS, run with console.

Tried:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1081630/How-to-Access-Static-Content-Files-in-MVC-Applicat